# Update not working in mysql php

Tags: php

When I tried to update data, I got same data but no updating. I can't find where went wrong. Updating goes without any error shown, but no updating when I view the code. So updating is not working. When I tried to update data, I got same data but no updating. I can't find where went wrong. Updating goes without any error shown, but no updating when I view the code. So updating is not working.

```
// Start the session
  session_start();
   $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'onlinetest');
  $sumid = $_SESSION['sumid'];
   if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
      $_SESSION['sumid'] = $_GET['sumid'];


      $query = "SELECT question, answer FROM sum WHERE sumkey = '$sumid' ";

       $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
       if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {

          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
          $question = $row['question'];
          $answer = $row['answer'];

          echo $question . $sumid;

        }
        mysqli_close($dbc); 

   }


 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
     //$Test = $_SESSION['testid'];
     $question1 = $_POST['question'];
     $answer1 = $_POST['answer'];
     $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'onlinetest');

    // $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'onlinetest');
     $query = "UPDATE sum SET question = $question1,answer = $answer1 WHERE sumkey = $sumid";

     mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

     echo 'New test name added';
     echo ''.$question1;
     mysqli_close($dbc);
     //exit();
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>Add sum</div>
<form method="post" action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <p>
    <label for="textarea"></label>
  <label>Question</label></p>
  <p>
      <textarea name="question" id="question" value="" cols="100" rows="9"><?php echo $question  ?></textarea>
  </p>
  <p><label>Answer</label>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <label for="textarea2"></label>
    <textarea name="answer" cols="100" rows="20" id="answer" value=""><?php echo $answer  ?></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type ="submit" value="ADD" name="submit"/>
  </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have errors turned on? try adding a try catch around your query

Answer (score 0):

> Updation [sic] goes without any error shown

Not surprising - your code doesn't check for errors. Try checking mysqli_error() after each mysqli_ operation.

BTW you're code is vulnerable to SQL injection, and storing transaction related data in the session is very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

As per your given script, first you are fetching record then updating data so may be due to that its not showing you updated record. Just reverse the condition means put update if condition above the fetching query. Then first it will update the record and then fetch the updated record.

Script are vulnerable for SQL injection, to prevent use **mysqli_real_escape_string ()** method.

```
// Start the session
  session_start();
  $sumid = $_SESSION['sumid'];
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
     //$Test = $_SESSION['testid'];
     $question1 = $_POST['question'];
     $answer1 = $_POST['answer'];
     $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'onlinetest');

    // $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'onlinetest');
     $query = "UPDATE `sum` SET `question` = '$question1', `answer` = '$answer1' WHERE `sumkey` ='$sumid'";

     mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

     echo 'New test name added';
     echo ''.$question1;
     mysqli_close($dbc);
     //exit();
 }



   $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'onlinetest');

   if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
      $_SESSION['sumid'] = $_GET['sumid'];    

      $query = "SELECT `question`, `answer` FROM `sum` WHERE `sumkey` = '$sumid' ";

       $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
       if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {

          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
          $question = $row['question'];
          $answer = $row['answer'];

          echo $question . $sumid;

        }
        mysqli_close($dbc); 

   }



?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>Add sum</div>
<form method="post" action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <p>
    <label for="textarea"></label>
  <label>Question</label></p>
  <p>
      <textarea name="question" id="question" value="" cols="100" rows="9"><?php echo $question  ?></textarea>
  </p>
  <p><label>Answer</label>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <label for="textarea2"></label>
    <textarea name="answer" cols="100" rows="20" id="answer" value=""><?php echo $answer  ?></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type ="submit" value="ADD" name="submit"/>
  </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- From what I'm seeing , you're confusing these 2 things in your code.

https://www.php.net/mysqli_close

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

2- As simcbean is telling you, you need to check-out for SQL INJECTION (Capitals so you're aware it's something really important.)

Hurry up before [Little Bobby TABLES](http://xkcd.com/327/) decides to try your website.

3- Personal recommendation :

Learn PDO prepared statement, it's easy to use once you get used to it and much safer.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

helpful code :

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    // Stuff

}else{
   // See what's wrong with the query
}
```

EDIT : If your data isn't integers, you need to quote your values in the UPDATE statement

```
$query = "UPDATE sum SET question = $question1,answer = $answer1 WHERE sumkey = $sumid";
$query = "UPDATE sum SET question = '$question1',answer = '$answer1' WHERE sumkey = '$sumid'";
```